# adding multiple rows to gridview

Tags: gridview, rows

I add one row to gridview dynamically, and also i want to add one more row to that and want to display all the rows ata atime.. how can i add rows to gridview dynamically..

Comment: In which programming language/framework? A little more detail would be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Assuming C#, [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3ce6k8.aspx).

Comment: Also, can you please rewrite the question with some semblance of grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if u r using asp.net n C# :

```
ChildTable table = GridView1.Rows[index].Parent as ChildTable;        //get that row
if (table != null)
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ColumnSpan = GridView1.Columns.Count;
    cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("New Row"));
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit and use the code tag to make the post more redable

Comment: You get a -1 for not writing english. "u", "r" and "n" are not wnglish words.